# '87% EXECUTING' Message When Running AppEngine App

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gradle-plugin

## Issue

When [testing an AppEngine application with a development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle#testing_your_application_with_the_development_server) for a Standard Environment app by running the command `gradle appengineRun` the message that logs in the console consistently is **87% EXECUTING**. A similar message **88% EXECUTING** consistently shows when running a Flexible Environment AppEngine Application with the command `gradle jettyRun`.

Does this mean there is an issue with running the application as there are no errors in the log?

### Log

```
Adams-MBP-2:coinverse-price adamhurwitz$ gradle appengineRun
2018-10-18 23:51:34.030:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2160ms to     org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2018-10-18 23:51:35.185:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.11.v20180605; built: 2018-06-05T18:24:03.829Z; git: d5fc0523cfa96bfebfbda19606cad384d772f04c; jvm 1.8.0_101-b13
2018-10-18 23:51:36.951:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started     c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@d554c5f{/,file:///Users/adamhurwitz/coinverse/coinverse-price/build/exploded-coinverse-price/,AVAILABLE}    {/Users/adamhurwitz/coinverse/coinverse-price/build/exploded-coinverse-price}
2018-10-18 23:51:36.953:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2018-10-18 23:51:36.954:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging disabled
2018-10-18 23:51:36.995:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started     NetworkTrafficSelectChannelConnector@60f00693{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:8080}
2018-10-18 23:51:37.010:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @5142ms
Oct 19, 2018 6:51:37 AM     com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService     startHotDeployScanner
INFO: Full scan of the web app in place every 5s.
Oct 19, 2018 6:51:37 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
Oct 19, 2018 6:51:37 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
Oct 18, 2018 11:51:37 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
<===========--> 87% EXECUTING [16s]
> :appengineRun
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the tests I've run thus far running locally and on the AppEngine servers are working so I'm going to say the 87 and 88 percents are fine!