# how to import jetty or gretty into my gradle script

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gretty

I am trying out gradle example **"todo-webapp-jetty"** from the book **Gradle In Action**. This can be found [here](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-in-action-source/blob/master/chapter03/todo-webapp-jetty/build.gradle). After several searches I came to know that jetty isn't supported anymore. Instead we need to use the gretty plugin(preferably the one that provided by org.gretty). But still no luck. My build script is same as the example's, just adjusted to use the gretty plugin.

Using the plugins block, this works fine , but only until I execute the jettyRun task. After executing the jettyRun task, the console is stuck at 87% :

```
plugins{
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.gretty' version '2.2.0'
}
............
    t<===========--> 87% EXECUTING [13s]a:509)
    > :jettyRun=--> 87% EXECUTING [12s]artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1800> :jettyRun=--> 87% EXECUTING [12s]
    > :jettyRunorg.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$Configurati<===========--> 87% EXECUTING [12s]ts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1037)
    > :jettyRunorg.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$Configurati<===========--> 87% EXECUTING [12s]nfiguration.java:1025)
    > :jettyRun 81 more
    <===========--> 87% EXECUTING [12s]
    > :jettyRun
    > IDLE
```

**EDIT 1 START** : Posting the complete stacktrace

```
D:\Practice\Gradle\GradleInAction\todo-webapp-jetty>gradle jettyRun -is
Initialized native services in: C:\Users\am064763\.gradle\native
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 48064). The daemon log file: C:\Users\am064763\.gradle\daemon\4.10.2\daemon-48064.out.log
Starting 2nd build in daemon [uptime: 10.343 secs, performance: 97%, GC rate: 0.50/s, tenured heap usage: 2% of 716.2 MB]
Using 8 worker leases.
Starting Build
another.gradle -->> This is executed during the initialization phase ---- timestamp  @ 2018-11-16T13:30:45
init.gradle -->> This is executed during the initialization phase ---- timestamp  @ 2018-11-16T13:30:45
zingAnother.gradle -->> This is executed during the initialization phase ---- timestamp  @ 2018-11-16T13:30:45
Settings evaluated using settings file 'D:\Practice\Gradle\GradleInAction\todo-webapp-jetty\settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'D:\Practice\Gradle\GradleInAction\todo-webapp-jetty\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'todo-webapp-jetty']

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'todo-webapp-jetty' using build file 'D:\Practice\Gradle\GradleInAction\todo-webapp-jetty\build.gradle'.
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'jettyRun' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':prepareInplaceWebAppFolder', task ':createInplaceWebAppFolder', task ':compileJava', task ':processResources', task ':classes', task ':prepareInplaceWebAppClasses', task ':prepareInplaceWebApp', task ':jettyRun']
:prepareInplaceWebAppFolder (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) started.

> Task :prepareInplaceWebAppFolder UP-TO-DATE
Skipping task ':prepareInplaceWebAppFolder' as it is up-to-date.
:prepareInplaceWebAppFolder (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.111 secs.
:createInplaceWebAppFolder (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) started.

> Task :createInplaceWebAppFolder UP-TO-DATE
Skipping task ':createInplaceWebAppFolder' as it is up-to-date.
:createInplaceWebAppFolder (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:compileJava (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) started.

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
Skipping task ':compileJava' as it is up-to-date.
:compileJava (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.048 secs.
:processResources (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) started.

> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
file or directory 'D:\Practice\Gradle\GradleInAction\todo-webapp-jetty\src\main\resources', not found
Skipping task ':processResources' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
:processResources (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:classes (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) started.

> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
Skipping task ':classes' as it has no actions.
:classes (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:prepareInplaceWebAppClasses (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) started.

> Task :prepareInplaceWebAppClasses UP-TO-DATE
Skipping task ':prepareInplaceWebAppClasses' as it has no actions.
:prepareInplaceWebAppClasses (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:prepareInplaceWebApp (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) started.

> Task :prepareInplaceWebApp UP-TO-DATE
Skipping task ':prepareInplaceWebApp' as it has no actions.
:prepareInplaceWebApp (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:jettyRun (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 5,5,main]) started.

> Task :jettyRun
Task ':jettyRun' is not up-to-date because:
  Task.upToDateWhen is false.

scanDir: D:\Practice\Gradle\GradleInAction\todo-webapp-jetty\src\main\webapp
scanDir: D:\Practice\Gradle\GradleInAction\todo-webapp-jetty\src\main\resources
scanDir: D:\Practice\Gradle\GradleInAction\todo-webapp-jetty\src\main\java
scanDir: D:\Practice\Gradle\GradleInAction\todo-webapp-jetty\build\classes\java\main
scanDir: D:\Practice\Gradle\GradleInAction\todo-webapp-jetty\build\resources\main
scanDir: C:\Users\am064763\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\3cd63d075497751784b2fa84be59432f4905bf7c\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
scanDir: C:\Users\am064763\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.websocket\javax.websocket-api\1.0\fc843b649d4a1dcb0497669d262befa3918c7ba8\javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar
scanDir: C:\Users\am064763\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.servlet\servlet-api\2.5\5959582d97d8b61f4d154ca9e495aafd16726e34\servlet-api-2.5.jar
scanDir: C:\Users\am064763\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.servlet\jstl\1.1.2\3375e43c620df4f1114959400ff9bb90d12a2feb\jstl-1.1.2.jar
fastReloadMap={:=[org.akhikhl.gretty.FileReloadSpec(D:\Practice\Gradle\GradleInAction\todo-webapp-jetty\src\main\webapp, null, null)]}
Enabling hot deployment with interval of 1 second(s)
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty9/2.2.0/gretty-runner-jetty9-2.2.0.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty9/2.2.0/gretty-runner-jetty9-2.2.0.jar]
Stopping scanner
Exception in thread "Thread-52" org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':grettyRunnerJetty9'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1054)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1028)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:444)        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty.getProperty(MetaBeanProperty.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.getProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryGetProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:171)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryGetProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:299)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.DefaultLauncher.getRunnerClassPath(DefaultLauncher.groovy:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:78)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:398)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:338)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:177)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.DefaultLauncher$_javaExec_closure7.doCall(DefaultLauncher.groovy:90)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:434)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:155)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:167)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.javaexec(DefaultFileOperations.java:224)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1102)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1097)
        at org.gradle.api.Project$javaexec$6.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.DefaultLauncher.javaExec(DefaultLauncher.groovy:89)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:352)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure4.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy:256)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure4.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:499)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find org.gretty:gretty-runner-jetty9:2.2.0.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty9/2.2.0/gretty-runner-jetty9-2.2.0.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty9/2.2.0/gretty-runner-jetty9-2.2.0.jar
Required by:
    project :
        at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:62)
<===========--> 87% EXECUTING [37s]artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.ComponentState.resolve(ComponentState.java:208)
> :jettyRunorg.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.ComponentState.resolve(ComponentState.java:196)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.ComponentState.getMetadata(ComponentState.java:152)
> :jettyRun=--> 87% EXECUTING [34s]artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.EdgeState.calculateTargetConfigurations(EdgeState.java:156)
<===========--> 87% EXECUTING [34s]artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.EdgeState.attachToTargetConfigurations(EdgeState.java:112)
> :jettyRunorg.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.attachToTargetRevisionsSerially(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:315)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveEdges(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:202)
> :jettyRun=--> 87% EXECUTING [33s]artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:155)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:126)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:123)
> :jettyRun=--> 87% EXECUTING [33s]artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:167)
<===========--> 87% EXECUTING [33s]artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:89)
> :jettyRun=--> 87% EXECUTING [33s]artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:73)
> :jettyRun=--> 87% EXECUTING [33s]artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$5.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:533)
> :jettyRun=--> 87% EXECUTING [33s]ations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
> :jettyRunorg.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
<===========--> 87% EXECUTING [32s]ations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
> :jettyRunorg.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfig> :jettyRun=--> 87% EXECUTING [32s]
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:509)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1800(DefaultConfiguration.java:123)
> :jettyRun=--> 87% EXECUTING [32s]artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1037)
> :jettyRunorg.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1025)
        ... 81 more
> :jettyRun=--> 87% EXECUTING [10s]
> :jettyRun
> IDLE
```

**EDIT 1 END**

But without the plugins block this, doesn't work and whenever I run the build I get below error message :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.gretty'

********

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Build file 'D:\Practice\Gradle\GradleInAction\todo-webapp-jetty\build.gradle' line: 3

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'todo-webapp-jetty'.
    > Plugin with id 'org.gretty' not found.
```

**EDIT 2 START** My **build.gradle :**

```
plugins{
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.gretty' version '2.2.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
}
```

**EDIT 2 END**

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the "normal" behavior of Gradle when execute tasks that are launching and running an application (like jettyRun or bootRun) : you will see the `<===---> XY% EXECUTING [...]` message while the application is executing..

For example with Spring Boot `bootRun` task you would have:

```
$ ./gradlew bootRun

> Task :bootRun

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.6.RELEASE)

<=========----> 75% EXECUTING [1m 58s]
> :bootRun
```

You should configuring logging in your application, to make some log traces available in STDOUT , you would normally see that the application is properly started.

**EDIT1**

From your stacktrace:

> Enabling hot deployment with interval of 1 second(s)
>   Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty9/2.2.0/gretty-runner-jetty9-2.2.0.pom]
>   Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty9/2.2.0/gretty-runner-jetty9-2.2.0.jar]
>   Stopping scanner
>   Exception in thread "Thread-52" org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':grettyRunnerJetty9'.

==> you need to add `jcenter()`  in your repositories block  , because `gretty-runner-jetty9-2.2.0.jar` required dependency is not available in  maven central repository.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    // your other repositories ...

}
```

Comment: see this similar question/answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887325/87-executing-message-when-running-appengine-app

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have edited my OP and added complete stacktrace with logging info enabled. As you can see, there exists a problem with the build run. It gives exception and complains `Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find org.gretty:gretty-runner-jetty9:2.2.0.` Even if I assumed this is normal, (which doesn't seem to be the case here), I'm still not able to locate the app at the default port 8080. Please let me know if I'm missing on anything.

Comment: You are right. adding jcenter repo resolved my issue. The app is up and running. Thanks again @MRicciuti . I am marking your answer as accepted. But one thing that still puzzles me is the second error of my OP , the one where build fails saying : `Plugin with id 'org.gretty' not found` when not usin gteh plugins block.

Comment: for this second question : to apply a plugin you need to use either `plugins {  ... }` syntax or `apply plugin : 'xyz'` : in the second case, if the plugin is not a core plugin delivered with Gradle (which is the case with gretty plugin), the `buildscript { }` block is mandatory. More info here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#example_applying_a_plugin_with_the_buildscript_block

Comment: being curious: if the `buildscript{}` block is mandatory for non-core plugins,(here, gretty) then my application shouldn't have got built in the the firstplace. But it did and is up and running. I haven't used the `buildscript{}` block anywhere in my build script. As I mentioned earlier, I'm going page by page through the Gradle in Action and haven't encountered the `buildscript{}` yet. But I am taking care of a few thing while learning, as the book uses gradle 1.7 and I'm using Gradle 4.10.2

Comment: I have updated my OP under EDIT 2 to include my build.gradle file

Comment: got it. makes complete sense. Please ignore my ignorance. I'm still learning.